# Can I safely delete database.bak from wallet folder?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet

In order to save space.
I cleaned it up and now my bitcind in freezing, but this might not be the cause.

Comment: The block files are 220GB. Why are you deleting random, small files that the software relies on?

Comment: It is not a block file. It is particular wallet file

Comment: I understand, but it’s meaninglessly small compared with the total storage used.

Comment: I store around 5000 wallets (and aim for a 1000000), each wallet can weight up to 6,5mB, so it is a significant space

Comment: Why on earth are you doing that?

Comment: I develop a project with users wallet management

Comment: That doesn’t require you to store a wallet for each user. Nobody else is doing this, so you’ve run into an edge case as a result- no service stores > 32GB of individual wallets.

Comment: 'Nobody else is doing this' newer was an argument :)
I can't manage wallet if i don't own it (if i don't have transactions history): I wouldn't even be able to get wallet balance